# Redircting stdout to file, but duplicating stderr to both file and terminal

Tags: shell, io-redirection, stdout, stderr

Redirecting `stderr` to file and duplicating `stdout` to both file and terminal is easy:

```
$ prog 2>error.log | tee output.log
```

`tee` will duplicate `stdout`, printing it to both terminal and `output.log`.

But what about redirecting `stdout` to file, and duplicating `stderr` to both terminal and file? How can that be accomplished? is there a `tee` equivalent that will duplicate `stderr` instead of `stdout`?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out it is just as easy...

```
prog 2>&1 > output.log | tee error.log
```

Comment: Sorry... can be deleted...